How do you calculate the number of skid patches on a fixie?
I'm aware there are calculators and spreadsheet files that do it. I'm asking about the analysis and the formulae.
I do not (yet) own a fixie, and so I need a primer. When you brake with your feet (if there are no brakes, or if you simply choose to slow down with your muscles), you need to use your braking leg (and it may be only one of your two legs) in its strongest position. That position closely mirrors the position of greatest strength when moving forward. Is this accurate?
After reading Sheldon Brown's eloquent write-up, I gather that the only sensible thing to do is to choose a chainring and sprocket whose teeth numbers are relatively prime. I suspect that the rule is as follows.
If the number of teeth on the sprocket is a prime number (11, 13, 17, 19 in the expected range), then you're golden, and there is nothing else to worry about.
If you need (or already have) a sprocket with any other number of teeth, then you should aim for a chainring with a prime number of teeth (37, 39, 41, 43, 47, 53 are all possible).
If they're relatively prime, and you're able to brake with both legs (is this hard? Is it, for example, as hard as breathing on both sides when you were learning to swim?), then the number of skid patches is equal to twice the number of sprocket teeth.
Can you elaborate or add points I don't see?

The most obvious thing you missed is that the tooth counts being relatively prime doesn't mean that either of them needs to be prime. For example, 49/16 is optimal because 49 has only 7 in its factors and 16 has only 2.
The full method for calculating skid patches for both legs is multiplying the number of chainring teeth by 2 and then simplifying. If the number of rear cog teeth is even, this doesn't increase the skid patch count. Even numbers are not prime, but they can be relatively prime with other numbers as shown above.

You're correct in suspecting that braking with either foot ambidextrously is not a natural thing. This is like many laterality phenomena across tons of sports disciplines... handedness in ball or racket sports, footedness in board sports etc. Cycling footedness is real; people who do a lot of stunts normally have a preferred forward foot. This is sometimes called the "chocolate foot". https://www.observedtrials.net/threads/chocolate-foot.25004/
So yeah, generally there is one foot that you will naturally prefer to have in front for skidding. You can train the other one and even them out, and it will double your skid patches.

Additionally,  there are calculators, like   https://www.bikecalc.com/archives/skid-patches.html   for double-checking one's results.

Your number of skid patches for a given forward foot is gear_ratio * N where N is an integer multiplier required to make the gear ratio a whole number.
So if you’re running 48 x 16 and you can only skid with your right foot forward, you have 3 skid patches. If you run 47 x 17 (like I used to 20+ years ago) and you can skid with either foot forward, you have 2 * a_lot_of_skid_patches.
Of course, I’m curious if you actually intend to skid a lot. If you’re putting brakes on the bike, there’s no reason to skid and this exercise is relatively pointless. Even without brakes, you’d learn to stop faster without skidding than you would skidding.

Re: "if you actually..." Might you choose to have brakes but not use them, but rather brake with your own muscles? The question is then whether you'll finish off halting to a stop (if needed urgently) by skidding or by activating the brakes. If you've been slowing down with your muscles, might skidding be the more natural thing to do? If you prefer, we can continue here https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/95879/48599 , rather than discuss this in comments.

@Sam7919 Not sure how that question is more relevant to this topic. My point is, if you need to stop fast, skidding is the worst way to do it. If don’t need to stop fast, why are you skidding?

If you stop to think for a moment, 48:16 gives you one skid patch: one full rotation on pedals turns the rear wheel exactly three rotations so it returns to the exact same position. Braking with both feet gives two skid patches, because half rotation turns the rear wheel one and half rotations.

Oh crap. You’re totally right @ojs. Really flubbed that, huh?

Naturally, there's an online calculator for this.

Check the first sentence in the question.
