In how many ways is riding a fixie similar to driving a manual-transmission car?
I keep reading (for example, here) that riding a fixie is similar to driving a manual-transmission car. As I'm a fan of the latter (have yet to be forced to own anything but), I'm wondering in how many ways they are similar.
I just understood one similarity. One doesn't need to change the brake pads quite as often. On a manual-transmission car it's enough to release the gas pedal early enough before red lights, and the car will slow down (until it's necessary to declutch and brake to a stop). Rather than dissipating the energy through heat by abrading the brake pads and rotors, the engine absorbs a (relatively minuscule) amount of extra heat. Likewise on a fixie it's possible to slow down by resisting the pedal movement (aside: does this resistance make you stronger, because, for example, it activates different muscles?). And, if you're willing to accept skid patches, you can forego using brakes, or skip installing them altogether.
In how many ways is riding a fixie similar to driving a manual-transmission car?

Both use 19th century technology that is superseded by 21 century advancements.

It is fine that you enjoy riding a fixie but it is not necessary to search artifficial "advantages". If you honestly want to exercise different leg muscles, start rowing. A rowing machine is quite sufficient.

@VladimirFГероямслава or running (especially uphill) which needs little or no equipment and that not bulky

@ChrisH I think it is actually mainly the downhill running and walking, that strains the muscles that cycling omits. Forward quads in particular.

@VladimirFГероямслава I have a (donated) rowing machine. If it weren’t a fancy thing I’d have already put it in the dumpster. (Hmm.. maybe that’s how I’m going to find the space for a fixie.)

@VladimirFГероямслава "What goes up...".  But my regular running route is optimised to go up the steep way and down a very gentle slope because of the impact on my knees of running down steep stuff, as well as the surface often being slippery.  I thin it depends what you're aiming for though.  Uphill on foot can be good cross-training to give benefits for cycling (making major use of muscles that are lightly used in cycling and at different extensions), while downhill is better for overall/balanced strength

@Sam7919 Do as you wish, of course, I do not own it either, but it is a much more efficient way to train different muscles instead of braking with your legs. Squads are another option.

Except the idea that there's less "interference" between you and the action of moving the vehicle, I don't see any analogy.
The attraction of fixies is linked to the simplicity, you control forward/backward movement with one control (pedals), steering with another one. In terms of operation, I wouldn't say that a manual car is more simple than an automatic, it adds in fact a layer of complexity. But still, a derailleur-equipped bike (with a 1x or IGH) is much simpler to operate than a manual transmission car (assuming that you have developed the balance skills required to ride a bicycle), and there's no interference once you have assimilated the principles.
On the similarity you mention (changing brake pads): you probably have a North-American bias. I'm saying it because I noticed that displacement is much higher than in Europe, where CO2-related regulations favour small engines with a turbo. I drive a Golf with a 1.0l engine and a turbo (which is the 3rd engine in range, starting from the least powerful), I can assure you that if you don't hit the brake, the car barely slows down when you release the gas pedal.

This must be the reason why disconnected sources come up with the claim in the question! It’s a spiritual similarity, more so than a technical one. You remain at all time engaged with the riding experience.

I'm unable to appreciate why a larger engine displacement would make engine-braking more effective. I asked: https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/98308/57044 .

Engine brake is caused by the action of compressing the air in the chambers, if there's more volume, there's more air to compress. In the case of "my engine", I doubt that the air that is coming in the chamber when braking is compressed, which lowers the compression rate. But let's see what the specialists answer.

Precisely. But if anything, you'd get more braking using a smaller-displacement engine, since the gas will compress faster.

@Sam7919 It will compress faster, but compressing it will require less work: I suspect is the work necessary for the compression that causes the deceleration, not the absolute pressure. Maybe add to complete your question: 1.0l turbo compressed vs 2.0l atmospheric. Engines designed for turbo have higher pressure at combustion, but very likely that the turbo is bypassed when "engine-braking".

A large share of the energy that goes into compressing air is also released when the air expands again. Compression release engine brake is a thing, but small vehicles generally don't have it.

@ojs but are the valves open or closed different the different stages? If they are closed during the compression, but open during the expansion, the effect on engine-braking would be limited, no?

Usually the valves are closed during compression (to stop compressed gas from flowing back to intake) and expansion (to capture the energy of pressurized gas with the piston). The jake brake makes engine braking more efficient, because the energy stored in compressed gas is released instead of recapturing it.

Overall it's just an analogy and not a very good one.
I suspect it was written by someone not used to driving a manual. There's no mechanical equivalence, you can engine brake on an automatic, and saying that a situation where you can't change gear is similar to one where you must is always going to be a stretch. In most manual vehicles (especially diesels which I'm used to) you end up having to change gear to get much engine braking anyway.
Engine braking can't stop you completely though, and leg-braking on a fixie can, even without skidding (so long as you can unclip quickly). So again the analogy falls down.
Note that in most jurisdictions you can't omit the front brake on a fixie as 2 independent braking systems are required. Braking via the pedals usually counts as one. Anyway you shouldn't omit the front brake because rear braking is less effective than front even when it works properly, and relying on it is prone to single point failures (e.g. a snapped or dropped chain)

That’s also it! (I also sometimes — with distant red lights, for example — shift down to brake. And in half those times I never reach a full stop, saving the energy to start from halting.) In both it’s possible to save your life by slowing down considerably (and halting with hand brakes if necessary), if your brake-pads-braking-system malfunctions or fails.

@Sam7919 to some extent you're shifting wear from the brakes to the clutch that way, but I do it quite a bit.  And I pick a gear to descend based on the speed I want and whether the engine is warm (makes a big difference) then only need to lightly touch the brakes for occasional fine tuning. I like an old-fashioned fully manual cable-actuated handbrake for that emergency reason, but note that in a few cars even the same user interface can operate a different sort of brake that can't be used in an emergency (I've never driven one personally)

You only wear your clutch if you do not rev-match.

@Sam7919 true; if you rev-match but not perfectly you only wear it a a little, which is realistic

I think the biggest similarity between manual shift cars and fixies is that you can tell vehicle speed simply from engine (or crank) revolutions per minute. Of course on a bicycle with gear shifting it’s also possible, but you have to know what gear you are in (I usually don’t know).
The utility of this is kind of limited. For a car it can make driving at a certain speed easier and I kind of miss that in electric cars. With a manual shift car when you are in second gear it’s pretty easy to obey a 30km/h speed limit because your engine is going to make a lot of noise if you go more than a few km/h above that.

I was driving down the street at 2500 rpm the tother day. How fast was I going?

@PaulH: Depends on your vehicle of course. But once you are familiar with it you should have a pretty good idea and in a car you usually always know which of the 5 gears you are using.

With an automatic and an ICE, you can also notice the variations in speed with the engine noise, not all automatic cars are electric ;). And about obeying the 30km/h speed limit, it really depends on the gear box: on mine, it's very hard to obey it: the first has too low ratios, so it makes a lot of noise, the second too high, so there's a risk of stalling (amplified by the small engine/turbo combination)

That’s indeed an important factor! Even without a speedometer, and without taking cues from the speed objects around you fly by, you always remain conscious of how fast you’re going, either through your pedaling or through how hard you’re pressing the gas pedal — plus you’re always conscious of the car’s gear (inside the city I seldom even remove my hand from the shifter, with my fingers gently touching, but not pushing in, the shifter).

@Sam7919 This is not a recommended practice. Just the weight of your hand  for a long time can damage the shifting. Besides, steering with just a one hand is not always ideal.

@VladimirFГероямслава I’m well aware of the first, hence why I specified “touching but not pushing in.” You’re right about the second. When there’s the slightest doubt, my shifting hand also grabs the wheel (and I remain in the same gear until the truck, or whatever, is farther).

Consider the modern car include's electric cars for the average driver and the dual clutch gear box, and most supercars and F1 have abandoned the traditional manual gear box. The modern bike includes the belt drive with or without internal gear hub, or a drive train that includes gearing in the bottom bracket and an optional electric motor. In both cases, modern drive system far exceeds the reliability of the drive systems of a few decades ago, despite the additional complexity. The simplicity of the older designs, balanced with the improved functionality of newer designs is no longer a practical advantage to all but a small minority of users.
They are both now twenty century play-things that have been superseded by far superior technology for day to day use. They legitimately still exist as a hobby item for enthusiasts but have no real practical application that is not better performed by more modern solution.
(Note I not judging anyone who wants to drive a manual or ride a fixie. After all, people still hunt with bow and arrows and listen to vinyl records).

Thanks for contributing a counterpoint. I'm not yet sure about fixies, but, mind you, the only reason car makers no longer (largely) make manual-transmission cars is that they are forced to (by environmental regulations). The committed group of potential buyers want cars with the latest bells and whistles. They are not Luddites. They just want to maintain control of the transmission. What I found striking is the premise that driving an MT car is the spiritual sibling of riding a bicycle that has no transmission, hence the question.

The reason why disparate sources express the similarity between riding a fixie and a manual-transmission car comes across clearly from reading the (at present) three answers. I'm collecting here my comments on the answers for the benefit of those who want a summary in one place.

More so than any mechanical or technical similarity, it's a spiritual kinship . Both riders remain engaged at all time with the experience of controlling their respective machine. Both riders continue to think "what am I going to do next?", even if that thinking gradually becomes second-nature or even subsconscious. (If you don't see spiritual matters as having anything to do with machines, look at it this way: you're closer to the machine, and it is in turn closer to the road, which puts you closer, and in control, to the road.)
Credit: Renaud
Even without a speedometer, and without taking cues from the speed objects around you fly by, you always remain conscious of how fast you’re going, either through how fast you're pedaling or through how hard you’re pressing the gas pedal. (It's a basic part of driving a manual-transmission car to be aware of the gear one is in. This is quite distinct from riding a geared bicycle, where one selects a gear incrementally and can largely ignore knowing the precise gear one is in.)
Credit: Michael
You have an alternative means for stopping your vehicle, aside from mechanical/hydraulic brakes. As a fixie rider you should not rely on braking by skidding, since a chain can break (and aside from legal matters such as the exact requirements in your jurisdiction). If your brakes do fail, you still stand a chance of coming to a stop using the bike's drivetrain (rather than, say, dragging your shoes on the ground). This could be your second parachute. You don't expect to need it, but it can be a last-ditch method to save your life by slowing down enough if your brake-pads-braking-system malfunctions or fails.
Credit: Chris H
As mentioned in the question, you can potentially replace your brake pads less often.
Your arms are more busy. They're not just steering. On a fixie you'll get a good workout wrestling with the handlebar on climbs. On a manual-transmission car managing the shifter, especially inside the city, will occupy your shifting arm for the duration of the ride.
You're more aware of the gradient. If the gradient changes from 0 to +2%, you may absent-mindedly shift down on a geared bike, or not even notice in an automatic-transmission car that you're on a slight uphill. On a fixie your legs will know that you started a mild climb. In a manual-transmission car you'll hear the engine working harder (and you'll unconsciously push the gas slightly to maintain your speed). You may choose to delay shifting up, if you were anyway accelerating, until you reach the top of the slope.

